# Ruby on Rails: Converting audio in background and uploading using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have two attachments in my model, original & modified.

My application allows a user to upload an audio file and the backend should convert it to a modified format.

The original file is uploaded to s3 using paperclip. Now I need to process this file in background and upload it to s3 as well & update the modified attachment in database.

The conversion from original to attachment happens via a simple system command, so I can invoke it from my ruby method. My question is what is the best way to schedule such jobs? Is delayed_job a good option for this where I just write a method to process the original file & save it and then call this method with a delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delayed_job` is a widely used solution for applications where you need something intensive to be done, but not right away. I would recommend it unless your user is going to need the modified file immediately.

Alternatives:

- Resque
- Sidekiq
- Navvy
- Queue Classic

For more options, see: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs

Comment: The user wouldn't need it immediately. It is sort of what you'd do on youtube, upload your video & then wait for youtube to finish processing it. Not like your video would be available instantly.

Would it make sense to have a cron job scheduled every 5 mins to call a ruby script which would then process all the unprocessed clips?

Comment: Delayed job is better in your case because it finds downtime and processes clips as it can. Cron is really good at doing things on a scheduled basis.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am going to wait for a while to see if someone has any other ideas on going about this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq is really good option to do background activities.

As it is going to be only one time activity so cron job is not ideally required.

Once you complete the process of uploading the original video, you can add jobs in Sidekiq with essentials parameters which will call worker class and do the rest of processing.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki

You also have good monitoring plugins to monitor processing of your jobs

https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq_monitor

Comment: Thanks. If i have sidekiq workers on two different servers against same database, could that cause an issue?

Comment: It should not be problem just make sure your code is thread safe

Comment: normal practice is to have a worker process running sidekiq, and sidekiq itself has multiple threads... that is better practice than running two different processes..